# how to create a simple pie-chart with invient-charts in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

for the last three hours I've been trying create a simple pie chart with invient-charts add-on in vaadin. I have read a lot about it , and put jquery.js and highcharts.js into webcontent file. I have modified my xml file to reference my application servlet. But it still doesn't work. I think I am doing these things wrong also. It is now driving me crazy. Can somebody provide me a simple tutorial about creating pie chart or any other chart example?

Comment: first that all, can you tell us a little bit more? for example, what exception are throwed or if the application works but the charts aren't rendered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide much information i post here the steps i took...

First that all i add the jquery and highcharts javascript files into webapp/js folder

now, edit your application servlet (the one that extends AbstractApplicationServlet)... there is a method **`writeAjaxPageHtmlHeader`** where you must add the url for the above two js files. that is here: https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/254632#_19_message_254632

i use maven in my project so, add the dependencies (if you aren't using maven add the jars into WEB-INF/lib folders)

later, i recompile the app widgetset with gwt:clean, vaadin:update-widgetset and gwt-compile maven plugins (if not using maven the command is Ctrl+6 i think)

finally the code for adding a chart into a component can be like this:

```
package com.x.y.z;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import com.invient.vaadin.charts.InvientChartsConfig;
import com.x.y.Manager;
import com.x.y.util.ApplicationHelper;

public class SalesChat extends AbstractChart {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -793793426045107314L;

    public SalesChat(InvientChartsConfig chartConfig) {
        super(chartConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void build() {

        Manager manager = (Manager)ApplicationHelper.getApplicationContext().getBean("manager");
        Map<String, Integer> sales = manager.weeklySales();

        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Sales");
        LinkedHashSet<DecimalPoint> points = new LinkedHashSet<DecimalPoint>();

        for( String string : sales.keySet() ){

            DecimalPoint point = new DecimalPoint(series, string, sales.get(string));
            point.setName( string + " " + sales.get(string).toString());
            points.add( point );
        }

        series.setSeriesPoints(points);
        addSeries(series);
        setWidth("279px");
        setHeight("240px");

    }
}
```

later...

```
InvientChartsConfig chartConfig = new InvientChartsConfig();
chartConfig.getTitle().setText("Sales");
chartConfig.getGeneralChartConfig().setType(SeriesType.PIE);

SalesChat chart = new SalesChat(chartConfig);
chart.build();

VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
layout.addComponent(chart);
```